# Angular performs unnecessary async validaton and throws ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular

I'm building my own form creator in angular 6.1.
I've made reproduction code - here it is: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svpkpx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

As in example. When You add some dynamically created fields angular performs async validation on field that is intact. It also throws `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` when those fields are in `ngFor` loop.

When there is no `ngFor` loop there is non `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kara from angular team found real issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25350#issuecomment-411226248

I was using `formGroup` as `@Input` and since it's an angular directive droved to problems.

Answer (score 0):

Well it will start working as expected if you simply move flag toggle method to component code insteed of doing it in template and force change detection run.

view:

```
  <button type="button" (click)="toggleShow()">show/hide</button>
```

component:

```
constructor(private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef){

}
  toggleShow(){
    this.show=!this.show;
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jnmqud?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: This solution works, but better would be to use a solution inside `input-wrapper`

Comment: I didn't notice you have custom component there.